# php function ord problem ord ("ü") return

Tags: php, ord

I'm passing some functions from VB to PHP
I have a problem using the php - **ord** method.

example :

```
ord ("a") = 97 OK
ord ("ü") = 195 NOT OK
```

**The result of ord ("ü") should be 50108**

in VB ASC ("ü") = 50108 is for a function to encrypt a password.

Comment: I guess it depend of the encoding used. You can configure default encoding in php.ini, try to set the same as you use in vb.net

Comment: Possibly, pass the string as UTF-8 bytes (`dim bytes Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Söme strüng")`).

Comment: Please post the code that you're trying to translate so we can figure out how to correctly answer this question without creating additional bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation the php function ord() cannot handle unicode characters. Beside that the documentation says:

> ord — Convert the first byte of a string to a value between 0 and 255

You can use the binary safe function [mb_ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php) instead.

```
<?php
var_dump(mb_ord('ü', 'ascii')); // => 195
var_dump(mb_ord('ü', 'utf-16') // => 50108
```

As you can see [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/00FC/) the decimal value in bytes is 195 and the strict decimal value is 50108. It all depends on the encoding of the char.

Comment: You are only getting the correct answer here because of it just so happens that when you mis-interpret a UTF-8 `ü` as a 2-byte UTF-16 sequence it comes up with the code point that matches literal bytes, which is actually `쎼`. This will explicitly break for 1 or 3 byte sequences, and I can only speculate what will happen for 4 byte sequences, or higher-codepoint 2-byte sequences.